# magento CE1.7.0.2 gives error while installing live site backup on local workstation

Tags: magento

i am facing below errors while installing live site backup on local workstation. I imported database backup too in mysql.

Renamed "local.xml.sample" to "local.xml".

renamed cache folder.
But yet it gives below error.

```
1. Warning: include_once(Mage/Core/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\app\Mage.php on line 50

 2.  Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Mage/Core/functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\wamp\www\app\code\local;C:\wamp\www\app\code\community;C:\wamp\www\app\code\core;C:\wamp\www\lib;.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\app\Mage.php on line 50

 3. Warning: include(Mage\Core\Model\App.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93

 4. Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage\Core\Model\App.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\wamp\www\app\code\local;C:\wamp\www\app\code\community;C:\wamp\www\app\code\core;C:\wamp\www\lib;.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93

 5. Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Model_App' not found in C:\wamp\www\app\Mage.php on line 670
```

Answer (score 0):

The most probable answer - you have incorrect hierarchy of your project files, ie you didn't copy whole project to your workstation. You need to check if app\code\core\Mage\Core folder is present and contains all the mentioned files.

Comment: resolved the problem before u were commenting. but thnx @Igor